# C++ fast ways to bind member functions

Tags: c++, boost, stl

I have a `class transition` and inside, a member function `rate`. I am asking for a method that would allow me to insert custom designed `rate`s into instants of `transition`, after those instants have been created, and would be fast at run-time!

I would like to optimize the code for speed. `rate` does simple computations but is called very frequently and many times by the program. So I guess I should avoid virtual functions... Question: what are the other best methods to achieve this in C++ (templates,boost,...)? Comments about the speed of a particular method would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
class transition {
public: 
  transition() : vec() {}
  double rate(T_vec::iterator a) { return ...; }
private: 
  T_vec vec;
};

/* custom rate #1 */
double my_rate_1( T_vec::iterator) { 
  /* do something */ 
  return ans; 
}

/* custom rate #2 */
double my_rate_2( T_vec::iterator) { 
  /* do something */ 
  return ans; 
}

const int N=10;

int main (void) {

  vector<transition*> ts(N);
  for(int i=0;i!=N;++i) ts[i] = new transition;

  /* How to efficiently implement the pseudo code that follows? */  

  ts[0]->rate = my_rate_1;
  ts[1]->rate = my_rate_2;

  /* ... */     

}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "name lookup"? that's done at compile time.

Comment: do you need static (compile time) solution (eg: templates) or a dynamic (runtime configurable) one like the strategy pattern?

Comment: @piotruś - it's pseudo code because I don't how this can be done with speed as objective in the first place (inserting custom functions at compile time)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath static (compile time, templates) would be fine!

Comment: if you need a runtime polymorphism, benchmark std::function vs bare function pointer they should be comparable yet std::function is more flexible and C++ish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least three ways to implement this.

Option 1 is virtual methods. You can't bind the method after you create the instance, but after the creation you can treat all the derived classes as `transition`.

```
class transition {
    ...
    virtual double rate(T_vec::iterator a) = 0;
};

class my_transition_1 : public transition {
    ...
    double rate(T_vec::iterator a) { ... }
};
class my_transition_2 : public transition {
    ...
    double rate(T_vec::iterator a) { ... }
};
```

Option 2 is callbacks. You can change the method at runtime, after you created the object. It's the most dynamic. It has slightly higher overhead in this case, because there is an extra copy construction of the iterator, and it is harder for the compiler to optimize away the indirect call.

```
class transition {
public:
    ....
    typedef double (*RateFunction)(T_vec::iterator a);
    void set_rate(RateFunction r) { _fun = r; }
    double rate(T_vec::iterator a) { return (*_fun)(a); }
private:
    RateFunction _fun;
};
double my_rate_1(T_vec::iterator a) {
    ...
}
...
transition t;
t.set_rate(my_rate_1);
```

Option 3 is functor templates. You have to specify everything at construction time, but this avoids the indirect call and has the best performance.

```
template <typename Rate>
class transition {
    double rate(T_vec::iterator a) {
        return Rate()(a);
    }
};
class my_rate_1 {
    double operator()(T_vec::iterator a) {
        ....
    }
};
class my_rate_2 {
    double operator()(T_vec::iterator a) {
        ....
    }
};

transition<my_rate_1> t1;
transition<my_rate_2> t2;
```

Option 4 is not extensible, but you avoid the indirect function call and have the opportunity to set the rate after creating the object.

```
class transition {
public:
    enum RateCode {
        RATE_1,
        RATE_2,
        ...
    }
    double rate(T_vec::iterator i) {
        switch (_rate_code) {
        case RATE_1: {
            ...
            return result;
            }
        case RATE_2: {
            ...
            return result;
            }
        default:
            assert(false);
        }
    }
    void setRate(RateCode r) { _rate_code = r; }
private:
    RateCode _rate_code;
}
```

Comment: Given that each design pattern is acceptable, how would you rank the three options by speed? If `rate` would consist of only a few arithmetic operations, say `return vec[0]*par + vec[1]*vec[2];`, what difference in performance between the slowest and the fastest one could be expected? thanks for a great answer, btw!

Comment: Option 3 is nice but I can't see how can I create a vector of objects / references first, and insert the rates later.

Comment: The speed would be: callback < virtuals << templates. I.e. templates would be noticeably faster than virtuals, and callbacks could be slightly slower than virtuals, but I expect that not by much. Of course the only way to know with 100% certainty is to benchmark. If you use the template solution, it's not possible to insert the different objects into containers.

Comment: I added a fourth option which will be faster than virtuals and allow you to insert the object into a container, but is not extensible.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to bind to arbitrary functions, check the [FastDelegate](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7150/Member-Function-Pointers-and-the-Fastest-Possible) article. There is also an [article of a more portable implementation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11015/The-Impossibly-Fast-C-Delegates) of the delegate idea.

If you can arrange your code such that the specific instance is known at compile time, this will be faster, assuming the compiler does its job well. The reason why it is faster is that a true delegate implies a call to a function pointer, and that breaks the speculative execution and pipelining in today's CPU's.

You might also want to read up on C++11. In C++11, lambda functions (inline written functions that can be passed around) are an important extension, and I would expect compilers to work hard to optimize them.